# How to make a "light" build of GCC with language supports etc. pruned?

Tags: c++, gcc, build

Basically I would like to make a light build of GCC with only C/C++ support. Can this be done easily or does it require manual tinkering with source?

Comment: Do you want only a subset of the full C++? Or to only install the C++ parts of GCC?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? 99% of the C compiler code is needed for C++, so I'm confused as to what you are trying to remove. Or do you mean `./configure languages=c,c++`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This is covered in [Installing GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/) and [Configuration](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html)

> --enable-languages=lang1,lang2,...
>       Specify that only a particular subset of compilers and their runtime libraries should be built. For a list of valid values for langN you can issue the following command in the gcc directory of your GCC source tree:
>
> ```
>          grep language= */config-lang.in
> ```
>
> Currently, you can use any of the following: all, ada, c, c++, fortran, go, java, objc, obj-c++. Building the Ada compiler has special requirements, see below. If you do not pass this flag, or specify the option all, then all default languages available in the gcc sub-tree will be configured. Ada, Go and Objective-C++ are not default languages; the rest are.

So, for your case using:

```
../gcc/configure --enable-languages=c,c++
```

should be sufficient, besides other needed options, of course.

See also [Building](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/build.html)

> Please note, that re-defining LANGUAGES when calling `make' does **not work** anymore!

Comment: Thanks, I somehow had missed that, even though I've been reading that manual for the past week or so!

Answer (score 6):

You can also use:

```
make install-strip
```

to reduce your installed size remarkably